# Grails throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I'm using withCriteria and the input contains a apostrophe

Tags: grails

So I have this piece of code that returns an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when the input uses an apostrophe. For example, the input is `Bo's Place`. This input triggers that error, when I use an apostrophe in the input, if there is no apostrophe, it works absolutely fine. Is there a way to avoid this? I want to allow that kind of input because it is a valid search term.

```
public static List<User> myCustomSearch(String query, List<Team> teams, List<Status> statuses) {
        if (!statuses) {
            return []
        }
        return withCriteria {
            inList('status', statuses)

            if (teams) {
                team {
                    inList('team', teams)
                }
            }

            if (query) {
                or {
                    ilike('username', "%$query%")
                    ilike('emailAddress', "%$query%")
                    ilike('firstName', "%$query%")
                    ilike('lastName', "%$query%")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing with the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error occurring when a last name contains an apostrophe is likely due to the way that the input is being processed within the ilike statements.

One solution would be to escape the apostrophe:
`query = query.replace("'", "''")`
However, in some scenarios this could produce 'unreliable' results.

An alternative solution would be to use parameterized queries to construct the search criteria. This can help you prevent SQL injection attacks and also handle special characters like apostrophes correctly:

```
public static List<User> myCustomSearch(String query, List<Team> teams, List<Status> statuses) {
    if (!statuses) {
        return []
    }
    def criteria = User.createCriteria()
    return criteria.listDistinct {
        'in'('status', statuses)
        if (teams) {
            team {
                'in'('team', teams)
            }
        }
        if (query) {
            or {
                ilike('username', "%${query}%", MatchMode.ANYWHERE)
                ilike('emailAddress', "%${query}%", MatchMode.ANYWHERE)
                ilike('firstName', "%${query}%", MatchMode.ANYWHERE)
                ilike('lastName', "%${query}%", MatchMode.ANYWHERE)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ilike statements now use MatchMode.ANYWHERE which allows for searching a pattern anywhere in the string. Notice that we're interpolating the query directly into the 'ilike' statements. Hope this helps.